unable to install properly M_Tree add-on for blender 4.0.0 on Mac with Apple silicon
unable to install properly M_Tree add-on for blender 4.0.0 on Mac with Apple silicon. it installs the add-on but doesn't let me "enable it". I have tried as low as 2.9 , 3.6, 4.0.0, 4.0.2, 4.2s of blender with 4_0_2 of M_tree but nothing is working.

Hi Tahir, it would be helpful if you could link to the add-on, but this external thread might help you along for now.

@Joachim thanks for the link to this thread. I also downloaded the blender 2.83 intel version as suggested in thread  for my Apple Silicon MacBook and also downloaded the M-tree 2_8_0 and now M_Tree is working for me.
